# Xcode unit testing not recognizing nil?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I am using Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68) in a pure Swift project. I ran into this monstrosity! Anyone knows how to "fix" this?

[image]

retrievedDate is declared as

```
var endDate: NSDate?
```

Comment: What does `print("retrievedEndDate -> \(retrievedEndDate) with type \(retrievedEndDate.dynamicType)")` output?

Comment: It prints     retrievedEndDate -> nil with type ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Optional<NSDate>>

Answer (score -1):

Probably

`XCTAssert(retrievedEndDate == nil, "retrievedEndDate is nil")`

Would work.

Also, you could rephrase your test to use `XCTAssertNotNil` instead.

Or as a workaround you could do:

```
guard let endDate = retrievedEndDate else { XCTFail("retrievedEndDate is nil") }
```

But that's not really pretty.

Comment: Updated answer with more info ;)

Answer (score -2):

I would rather check that the retrievedEndData is an option. For example:

```
let retrievedEndDate : NSDate? = nil
```

should yield true when asserting like:

```
XCTAssertNil(retrievedEndDate)
```